# Jenkins job stucks after Stopping PabotLib process

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, robotframework, python-2to3

I'm running jenkins job and trying to set my environment from python 2 to 3. It's going pretty well now and my tests run well under python3 from jenkins. But when I try to run the same test under python2 the job stucks at stopping PabotLib.

[image: job stucks at stopping PabotLib]

However it runs perfectly from commandline.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That issue usually happens if/when you start processes and/or open files  during your test run and those processes/files are not stopped/closed.

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thank. But that'd be pretty strange cause I havent changed anything in the test.

Comment: Well, if they are external processes,  they can change without you changing any of your test code.. OS behaviour of stopping those can fail due to multiple reasons too.

Comment: Specifically in windows .. Even robotframework's own tests failed to stop external processes at one point in Windows because "Terminate Process" keyword just didnt work correctly  and for this reason, i made my own process killer helper for my personal project @ https://github.com/rasjani/robotframework-seleniumtestability/blob/master/src/Helpers/__init__.py to workaround similar issue..

Comment: Thx rasjani. What you said was right. The webdriver closes but the browser stays alive my fault. But I don't really understand why does it cause problem when it runs under python2 and not under python3

Comment: Pure speculation: standard libraries (most likely psutil) has gotten some updates since moving out from python2.7 to 3.X  .. Can't say for sure.